# ImageView not initialized

Tags: java, android, imageview

I'm testing out my system for hitboxes for a game i'm making. The problem is that i get the following error in my ball class: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

It happens in the first line in the constructor method in the ball class.
Does anyone know if i'm doing anything wrong?

main class:

```
package xander.mazetestapp;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {
    private TextView text;
    private SensorManager sManager;
    private int a = 300;     //x position
    private int b = 300;     //y position
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    ball playingBall;
    wall mazeWall;
    float show = 1;
    float hide = 0;
    boolean allowedMovement[] = {true, true, true, true};
    int maxX = 0;
    int maxY = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    playingBall = new ball();
    mazeWall = new wall(hide, R.id.wall1);

}

//when this Activity starts
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    /*register the sensor listener to listen to the gyroscope sensor, use the
    callbacks defined in this class, and gather the sensor information as quick
    as possible*/
    sManager.registerListener(this, sManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}

//When this Activity isn't visible anymore
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    //unregister the sensor listener
    sManager.unregisterListener(this);
    super.onStop();
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    //Do nothing.
}

public void limitMovement(ball ball, wall wall) {
    float wy = (ball.getWidth() + wall.getWidth()) * (ball.getCenterY() - wall.getCenterY());
    float hx = (ball.getHeight() + wall.getHeight()) * (ball.getCenterX() - wall.getCenterX());

    if (wy > hx) {
        if (wy > -hx) {//top
            allowedMovement[1] = false;
        } else {//left
            allowedMovement[2] = false;
        }
    } else {
        if (wy > -hx) {//right
            allowedMovement[3] = false;
        } else {//bottom
            allowedMovement[0] = false;
        }
    }
}

public boolean intersect(ball ball, wall wall) {
    //top left corner of the ball
    if (ball.getTopLeftX() >= wall.getTopLeftX() && ball.getTopLeftX() <= wall.getTopRightX()) {
        if (ball.getTopLeftY() >= wall.getTopLeftY() && ball.getTopLeftY() <= wall.getBottomLeftY()) {
            limitMovement(ball, wall);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //top rigth corner of the ball
    if (ball.getTopRightX() >= wall.getTopLeftX() && ball.getTopRightX() <= wall.getTopRightX()) {
        if (ball.getTopRightY() >= wall.getTopLeftY() && ball.getTopRightY() <= wall.getBottomLeftY()) {
            limitMovement(ball, wall);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //bottom left corner of the ball
    if (ball.getBottomLeftX() >= wall.getBottomLeftX() && ball.getBottomLeftX() <= wall.getBottomRightX()) {
        if (ball.getBottomLeftY() >= wall.getTopLeftY() && ball.getBottomLeftY() <= wall.getBottomLeftY()) {
            limitMovement(ball, wall);
            return true;
        }
    }

    //bottom rigth corner of the ball
    if (ball.getBottomRightX() >= wall.getBottomLeftX() && ball.getBottomRightX() <= wall.getBottomRightX()) {
        if (ball.getBottomRightY() >= wall.getTopLeftY() && ball.getBottomRightY() <= wall.getBottomLeftY()) {
            limitMovement(ball, wall);
            return true;
        }
    }


    return false;

}


public void move(int x, int y) {
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams alp = playingBall.getLayoutParams();
    int maxMovementX = Math.abs(x);
    int maxMovenentY = Math.abs(y);
    int stepsTakenX = 0;
    int stepsTakenY = 0;

    while (maxMovementX > stepsTakenX || maxMovenentY > stepsTakenY) {
        //up 0, down 1, right 3, left 2
        if (stepsTakenX < maxMovementX) {
            stepsTakenX = stepsTakenX + 1;
            if (x > 0 && allowedMovement[3] == true) {//right
                playingBall.setCenterX(playingBall.getCenterX() - 1);
                a = a - 1;
            }
            if (x < 0 && allowedMovement[2] == true) {//left
                playingBall.setCenterX(playingBall.getCenterX() + 1);
                a = a + 1;
            }
        }

        if (stepsTakenY < maxMovenentY) {
            stepsTakenY = stepsTakenY + 1;
            if (y > 0 && allowedMovement[1] == true) {//down
                playingBall.setCenterY(playingBall.getCenterY() - 1);
                b = b - 1;
            }
            if (y < 0 && allowedMovement[0] == true) {//up
                playingBall.setCenterY(playingBall.getCenterY() + 1);
                b = b + 1;
            }
        }

    }

    alp.leftMargin = a;
    alp.topMargin = b;
    playingBall.setLayoutParams(alp);
}


@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    //if sensor is unreliable, return void
    if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE) {
        return;
    }

    //else it will output the Roll, Pitch and Yawn values
    x = Math.round(event.values[2]) / 3;
    y = Math.round(event.values[1]) / 3;

    if (x > 15) {
        x = 15;
    }
    if (x < -15) {
        x = -15;
    }
    if (y > 15) {
        y = 15;
    }
    if (y < -15) {
        y = -15;
    }


    //kleinere x is naar links
    //kleinere y is naar boven
    //balk1 is boven
    //balk2 is onder
    //balk3 is links
    //balk 4 is rechts


    move(x, y);


    text.setText("Width: " + playingBall.getWidth() +
                    "    Height: " + playingBall.getHeight() +
                    "   B x: " + playingBall.getCenterX() +
                    "   B y: " + playingBall.getCenterY() +
                    "   W  x: " + mazeWall.getCenterX() +
                    "   W  y: " + mazeWall.getCenterY() +
                    "  wall LB x: " + mazeWall.getTopLeftX() +
                    "  wall LB y: " + mazeWall.getTopLeftY() +
                    "Width: " + mazeWall.getWidth() +
                    "    Height: " + mazeWall.getHeight()


    );

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

ball class:

```
package xander.mazetestapp;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;



public class ball extends AppCompatActivity {

private int centerX;
private int centerY;
private int topLeftX;
private int topRightX;
private int bottomLeftX;
private int bottomRightX;
private int topLeftY;
private int topRightY;
private int bottomLeftY;
private int bottomRightY;
private int width;
private int height;
public ImageView ballImage;


public ball(){
   ballImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ball);

    centerX =(int) ballImage.getX();
    centerY = (int) ballImage.getY();
    width = ballImage.getWidth();
    height = ballImage.getHeight();

    setCorners();
}

private void setCorners() {
    topLeftX=(centerX-(width/2));
    topLeftY=(centerY-(height/2));

    topRightX=(centerX+(width/2));
    topRightY=(centerY-(height/2));

    bottomRightX=(centerX+(width/2));
    bottomRightY=(centerY+(height/2));

    bottomLeftX=(centerX-(width/2));
    bottomLeftY=(centerY+(height/2));
}

public int getWidth(){
    return width;
}

public int getHeight(){
    return height;
}

public int getCenterX(){
    return centerX;
}

public int getCenterY(){
    return centerY;
}

public int getTopLeftX(){
    return topLeftX;
}

public int getTopRightX(){
    return topRightX;
}

public int getBottomLeftX(){
    return bottomLeftX;
}

public int getBottomRightX(){return bottomRightX;}

public int getTopLeftY(){
    return topLeftY;
}

public int getTopRightY(){
    return topRightY;
}

public int getBottomLeftY(){
    return bottomLeftY;
}

public int getBottomRightY(){
    return bottomRightY;
}

public void setCenterX(int x){
    centerX=x;
}

public void setCenterY(int y){
    centerY=y;
}









public RelativeLayout.LayoutParams getLayoutParams(){
    return (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) ballImage.getLayoutParams();

}

public void setLayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams alp){
    ballImage.setLayoutParams(alp);
}
```

Comment: ball class is activity so initialize imageview in oncreate method

Answer (score 1):

I guess Hardik is right ball class is an activity as you have used extends appCompatActivity. So you have to initialize the image view in onCreate method.

Answer (score 0):

For any activity initialisation takes place after onCreate() you need to get the ImageView reference in the onCreate() and make sure you set the layout in setContentView() and then get the ImageView reference

Answer (score 0):

Your ball class is not actually an activity. It is a simple class. You do not need to extends AppCompatActivity. Just make the constructor of ball class with  the parameter as a context and then using that context you can get imageview.

i.e.

Changes in ball.java are below:

remove "extends AppCompatActivity" and make it simple class.

```
public ball(Context context){
   ballImage = (ImageView) context.findViewById(R.id.ball);
    centerX =(int) ballImage.getX();
    centerY = (int) ballImage.getY();
    width = ballImage.getWidth();
    height = ballImage.getHeight();
    setCorners();
}
```

Changes in main.java are below:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    sManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    playingBall = new ball(this); // Here we pass the context of the current activity

    mazeWall = new wall(hide, R.id.wall1);

}
```